# Input type - Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a newsletter sign up form on a site and I can't seem to figure out why the email section input type is set to 'tel' meaning on mobile, users get only access to the numerical keypad and not the actual keyboard. I am quite new to this, which is why I am after some help.

It is the homepage to, the subscribe form down the bottom: https://www.australianwildlife.org/

Can someone please advise how I might be able to change it to input ="email"? I have attached a screenshot where I can see it is set to input="tel"

Here is the contact form 7 code:

```
<div class="form-content">
<div class="subscribe_form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-20">
                [awctext* first-name label "First name"]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-20">
                [awctext* last-name label "Last name"]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-20">
                [awcemail* email label "Email"]
            </div>

        </div>
```

.col-md

[submit class:bttn class:secondary-alt1-bg class:btn class:radius-none class:white-color class:submit-btn class:ripple "Subscribe"]

[Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn0sL.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you just switch to regular `[text]` or `[email]` form tags?

Comment: Because whoever made the theme before me has it set that awcemail is styled correctly, if I just use [email] it looks different

Comment: It's probably easier to match their style, than to fix their bad form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is part of your theme, not so much part of contact form 7. The shortcode starts with awc, which should stand for Australian Wildlife Conservancy. Somewhere in the theme’s files these shortcodes are added. The bug should be in there.

You can start searching for `awcemail` on your file system in both the `wp-content/themes` folder and `wp-content/plugins` folder (since it might have been implemented in a plugin). If you cannot find it, try searching for the `add_shortcode` and see whether you can find out whether `awcemail` is a shortcode and where it is added. You can also do a file search for the following:

`type="tel"`

`type='tel'`

If that doesn't work you should found out how the code for your contact form is actually parsed. If you know which file(s) are responsible for that you might find in them where the `[awcemail` part is converted to the actual html.

If that doesn't work, get in contact with the developer, or post (parts of) the code in a github, for example, so we can examine it. I'm sure that if you post all the code, we are able to help you fix this bug, but that is up to you, of course.

Comment: Thanks for that, I can't seem to locate it anywhere in the theme files. What exactly am I looking for? - Brody

Comment: I managed to find a if statement that wasn't set up correctly, fixed thanks to your guidance on where to find it. Thanks mate!